# UITabBarController Like Apple's Remote App

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller

Does anyone have an idea how Apple implemented the UITabBarController in the iOS Remote App (for controlling iTunes)?

Specifically, how the Remote will show a blacked out Tab Bar until the user selects an iTunes library (in a modal view), after which the tabs show "Songs," "Artists," etc.

Where would they have placed the logic to check that an iTunes library is selected and how do they blackout the tabs until it is?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You basically can set the UITabBarItem's enabled property to false.

Like:

```
[tabBarItem setEnabled: NO]; // to disable
```

Comment: Thank you very much.  I'm still wondering how to then go back and enable the tabs once the "library" is selected, but I'm working on it, so hopefully it'll jump out at me.

Comment: So, what I ended up doing is making the App Delegate's UITabBarController a property.  If the App's logic determines the user should be presented with blank tabs (like the Remote app), then it creates the controller by pushing non-tab views.  After the user makes changes (as in selecting a Library in the Remote app), the app can use the property to point back to the TabController and set up the tabs.  I guess this is how Apple did it?

Comment: That's how I would do it. But I wonder if you can just the UITabBarItem's enabled property to false. That might disable all UITabBarItem's it contains.